# Elasticsearch failed to execute script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Elasticsearch version 7.7.0

This is the part of the mapping:

```
const PROFILE_MAPPING = {
  mappings: {
    properties: {
      _userLocation: {
        type: "geo_point"
      },
      _ignoredBy: {
        type: "nested"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

_ignoredBy data example:

```
 [{
        "until" : "2020-12-03T16:20:43.176Z",
        "user" : <USER_ID>
  }]
```

and this is the script I'm running to update it:

```
    await client.update({
        index,
        id: target,
        refresh: "wait_for",
        body: {
          script: {
            source:
              "ctx._source._ignoredBy.removeIf(item -> item.user == 
    params.by.user);ctx._source._ignoredBy.add(params.by)",
            params: {
              by: {
                user: initiator,
                until: addSeconds(new Date(), ignoreInterval) 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "failed to execute script"
          }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to execute script",
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": ["item -> item.user == params.by.user);", "^---- HERE"],
          "script": "ctx._source._ignoredBy.removeIf(item -> item.user == params.by.user);ctx._source._ignoredBy.add(params.by)",
          "lang": "painless",
          "position": { "offset": 32, "start": 32, "end": 69 },
          "caused_by": { "type": "null_pointer_exception", "reason": null }
        }
      },
      "status": 400
    }
```

The weird thing is that this works 99% of the time but errors are appearing on logs and can't figure out what's the reason. The params passed in are 100% there as they appear on logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such null pointers are hard to wrap one's head around but my hunch is that there's something off with `ctx._source._ignoredBy` itself.

In that spirit, I'd suggest to add one more check before I'm calling `.removeIf` on it -- perhaps initialize it in case it's `null`:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source._ignoredBy == null) {ctx._source._ignoredBy = []; }  ctx._source._ignoredBy.removeIf(item -> item.user == params.by.user); ctx._source._ignoredBy.add(params.by)",
    "params": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, if by any chance the `_ignoredBy` is empty, does it raises null pointer too, ie `item` does not exist? I do not know Java at all.

Comment: There's too little information for me to say that with confidence but I think so, yes. Painless is java-like so the same principles apply. Give my script a shot, wait a bit, and see if you're still seeing the 1% errors.